# FALHA DE SEGMENTAÇÃO EM NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, falha-de-segmentação, nasm

**Atualização no código:** *segui as dicas e tentei interromper o loop na seção update. Ainda estou trabalhando na falha de segmentação, contudo. E preciso checar esse loop, acho que não está totalmente certo isso....*

Olá, estou escrevendo um código para realizar uma série de tarefas sequenciais em sintaxe NASM. A principio eu não conseguia nem compilar, mas agora embora compile, e execute o linker, ao executar o programa no terminal recebo a mensagem "Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)". Como sou péééééssima nisso, e estou só começando a entender qual a lógica do Assembly, não consigo encontrar o erro.
Alguém tem alguma dica?
É pra linux, mas nos slides que eu peguei de algumas aulas na internet, no ubuntu o pessoal usa esse mov eax,1 - int 80h como chamada de sistema mesmo.

```
section .data

        array   DB 30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,82,30,30,30
        divisor DB 10
        result  DW 0

section .text                                                                   
    global _start
    
_start:
        
        xor ax,ax
        xor cx,cx
        xor bl,bl
        
        mov si,[array+0]
        mov cx,20                                               
        mov bl,[si]                                                 
        
loopx:
        cmp [si],bl                                 
        jle update                                  

resume:
        inc  si                                                         
        loop loopx                                      
        
update:
        mov bl,[si]
        cmp [array+80],bl
        je  c_soma                          
        jmp resume                                  
        
        xor bh,bh                   
        mov [result],bx     
        mov ax,[result]         
        mov bl,[divisor]        
        div bl                  
        
        mov bl,al                       
        
        jmp c_soma          
        
        
body_soma:
        sub al,1    
        add bl,al   
        jmp c_soma  
        
        
c_soma:
        cmp al,0            
        jne body_soma   

        mov eax,1
        int 0x80
```

o objetivo é fazer uma sequencia de ações: primeiro percorrer o vetor de 20 posições e encontrar o menor valor, atualizando o registrador. Ao terminar de percorrer o vetor, deve registrar apenas o dígito da dezena, por isso a divisão por 10, e enfim fazer uma soma aritmética para essa dezena encontrada. Escolhi todos iguais com a dezena de 3 para poder ter algo com o que somar 3+2+1, por isso o dec. Ele não retorna para a tela, pois uso seeReturn.sh para ver o resultado da operação. Sim, ele parece que não fez nada, mas a ideia é operar valores, vetores e endereços mesmo.

no terminal uso `nasm -f elf -o nomedoarquivo.o nomedoarquivo.asm` para compilar e `ld -m elf_i386 -s -o nomedoarquivo nomedoarquivo.o` para o linker.

**ATUALIZANDO A PERGUNTA:** *tem alguma forma de percorrer o vetor a partir da primeira posição sem definir ponteiro? Tentei offset array, mas deu erro de sintaxe também.*

Comment: qual seria seu objetivo com esse programa? ele tem algumas contas, mas não faz nenhuma operação de E/S - então mesmo que funcione, vai terminar sem parecer que fez nada.

Comment: outra - ele é pra Windows/DOS né? Lembro vagamente do int 80h com código "1" ser pra encerrar o programa.  Precisa marcar, pq em Mac e Linux seria diferente.

Comment: o objetivo é fazer uma sequencia de ações: primeiro percorrer o vetor de 20 posições e encontrar o menor valor, atualizando o registrador. Ao terminar de percorrer o vetor, deve registrar apenas o dígito da dezena, por isso a divisão por 10, e enfim fazer uma soma aritmética para essa dezena encontrada. Escolhi todos iguais com a dezena de 3 para poder ter algo com o que somar 3+2+1, por isso o dec. Ele não retorna para a tela, pois uso seeReturn.sh para ver o resultado da operação. Sim, ele parece que não fez nada, mas a ideia é operar valores, vetores e endereços mesmo.

Comment: É pra linux, mas nos slides que eu peguei de algumas aulas na internet, no ubuntu o pessoal usa esse mov eax,1 - int 80h como chamada de sistema mesmo.

Comment: no terminal uso nasm -f elf -o nomedoarquivo.o nomedoarquivo.asm para compilar e ld -m elf_i386 -s -o nomedoarquivo nomedoarquivo.o para o linker. Por isso global _start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estou e enferrujado, ou já arriscaria uma resposta mais assertiva - mas tá vendo o `mov si,[array+0]`  - isso move o Valor encontrado no endereço "array + 0" para o registrador `SI` (o valor "30") - e aí em `mov bl, [si]` você está usando o valor em SI como um ponteiro (endereço de memória) - isso sozinho já causaria o segfault.

Primeira tentativa então - trocar aquela instrução para `mov si, array+0`.

---

Atualização -
demorou mas encontrei - como você sabe, o código que você está escrevendo é basicamente assembler de 16bit (registradores AX, tem largura 16bit, al e ah são duas metades de 8bit, etc)... isso é do tempo do 8086 - e ali, há um problema sério de endereçamento - para endereçãr mais 2 ^ 16 bytes de memória (64KB) essa arquitetura fazia uso dos "registradores de segmento" (DS, ES, CS e SS) para compor o endereço final em até 1MB de memória.

Com a arquitetura de 32bits, do 386, passou a ser possível escrever programas endereçando a memória diretamente, sem o uso desses registradores de segmento (os registradores podiam endereçar até 4GB de memória diretamente - o S.O. pode usar registradores internos para gerenciar tabelas de memória intermediárias para o chegar no endereço real e endereçar mais de 4GB) -

Mas, digressão a parte, por padrão o formato elf32 do Linux assume que seu código é de 32bit, e vai somar um valor constante em todos os seus  endereços de memória  na hora de compilar - esse valor por padrão é 0x08048000 - então, quando se tenta carregar o endereço de "array" em `SI` ele tenta por o endereço de array + 0x08048000 - que não cabe em `SI` por que ele é só um registrador de 16bits do tempo do 8086.

O problema todo então se resolve se em vez de usar `SI` vocè usar `ESI` como registrador de endereço - essa é a versão 32bit do SI (os 16 bits inferiores são o SI) .  Com o nasm no Linux estamos escrevendo código que vai rodar no "modo protegido" de 32bits e, mesmo podendo limitar o algoritmo e instruçõs aos registradores de 16 bit legados, pode-se fazer uso a vontade de todos os registradores de 32bit dessa arquitetura.

Bom - eu desfiz um "nó" na sua lógica - fica mais fácil de acompanhar, e coloquei um salto incondicional depois da instrução `loop` para o ponto onde é feita a soma.

O data section no final foi mais algo que "aconteceu" nas minhas tentativas de acertar.

```
section .text
  global _start
_start:
        
        xor ax,ax
        xor cx,cx
        xor bl,bl
       
        mov esi, array
        mov cx,20                                               
        mov bl,[esi]                                                 
loopx:
        cmp [esi],bl                                 
        jg not_update                                  

        mov bl, [esi]
not_update:

        inc  si                                                         
        loop loopx                                      
        
end_loop:        
        xor bh,bh                   
        mov [result],bx     
        mov ax, bx
        mov bl,[divisor]        
        div bl                  
        
        mov bl,al                       
        
        jmp c_soma          
        
        
body_soma:
        sub al,1    
        add bl,al   
        jmp c_soma  
        
        
c_soma:
        cmp al,0            
        jne body_soma   

        mov eax,1
        int 0x80

section .data
        array   DB 30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,82,30,30,30
        divisor DB 10
        result  DW 0
```

E por fim, mas não menos importante, link para a resposta no SOEN onde consegui entender a questão do endereçamento:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35000389/108205

Comment: Não funcionou, mas acho que mesmo por conta da sintaxe. Se eu usar o ponteiro como endereço, ele dá mismatch no tamanho dos registradores de origem e destino (2 bits - 8 bits).

Comment: o registrador "si" tem 16 bits de largura -  acomanhei o seu programa todo agora, e compilei um "hellor world" aqui pra mim - achei outro problema: quando acaba o `loop` ele não "sabe" que tem que ir para `body_soma` - vai continuar na próxima instrução  - e vai chegar no `jmp resume ` - basicamente um loop infinito.

Comment: Obrigada!!!! Depois da sua explicação, acho que vou precisar estudar um pouquinho mais essa lógica entre 16-32 bits....Uma parte muito importante foi essa solução para o loop, pois eu estava fixada em no if-not e acabava sempre caindo no loop infinito. Obrigada mesmo!

Comment: é importante entender que a instrução "loop" não é algo automático tipo `for` ou `while` em C - éo equivalente `dec cx; jnz <alvo>`   quando CX chega em 0, continua na instrução abaixo.

Comment: usa 32 bits - vi que nos ultimos 15 ou 20 anos,  a história de chamar `int 80h`  também ficou pra trás, mesmo em 32bit - o correto é usar a instrução `sysenter`: http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html  (é que `systenter`  é uma "novidade" do Pentium II, não existia no 386 original)